# BASH List Possible Files and Select One

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to be able to run a bash script, have it list possible files as options to select one, and then transfer that file via scp to a destination...

The scp part is no problem, but how do I get a list of the files and be able to select one is proving challenging for me...

```
$ ./script
Please select a file.
[0] ~/Desktop/ScreenShot-04-06-19-01:02:33.png
[1] ~/Desktop/ScreenShot-04-06-19-01:03:33.png
[2] ~/Desktop/ScreenShot-04-06-19-01:04:33.png
Enter File Index ID:
```

Comment: Could try putting the results of your file listing into an array and then select the array element based on what the user selects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I'd do in a bash script (would also work in a POSIX `sh` script):

```
echo 'Please select a file.'

n=0
for img in ~/Desktop/ScreenShot-*.png
do
    n=$((n+1))
    printf "[%s] %s\n" "$n" "$img"
    eval "img${n}=\$img"
done

if [ "$n" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo >&2 No images found.
    exit
fi

printf 'Enter File Index ID (1 to %s): ' "$n"
read -r num
num=$(printf '%s\n' "$num" | tr -dc '[:digit:]')

if [ "$num" -le 0 ] || [ "$num" -gt "$n" ]
then
    echo >&2 Wrong selection.
    exit 1
else
    eval "IMG=\$img${num}"
    echo Selected image is "$IMG"
fi
```

Comment: Why would you use `eval "img$n"` instead of an array? `img[$n]=...`?

Comment: Coders Choice. Readability. Coder/Maintainer Experience level. Shell Choice. OS/Platform variations. Probably more -- all I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @muru *"also work in a POSIX sh script"* (select/arrays not supported)

Comment: @alecxs https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/511137/revisions

Comment: @alecxs poor intruders with low rep aren't welcomed in king's territory. Be safe ;) The unfortunate dark side of SE network

Comment: normal member: searches for duplicates and flag the question. power member: read the duplicate, post as answer and collect the votes :D

Comment: @alecxs actually yes :D

Comment: This needs a `shopt -s nullglob` before the `for` statement, to handle the case where nothing matches the wildcard.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use select from bash :

```
$ cat myscript
PS3="Enter File Index ID: "
echo "Please select a file."
select file ; do
  [ "$file" ] &&
   {
     echo "$file"
     break
   } ||
   {
     echo "bad choice"
     break
   }
done
```

and you call it this way :

```
myscript ~/Desktop/*.png
```

PS : Rename script to myscript because script is a command.
see `man script`

Comment: @IrfanLatif's answer is vilified for using `eval`, but his doesn't have a command injection vulnerability (after my minor edit) while this one has (`[ $file ]` with `$file` unquoted, try for instance with a file called `-v a[$(reboot)] -o .png`)

Comment: The point is we know `eval` is dangerous (hence Irfan did the `tr -cd '[:digit:]'` to sanitize the value), but `[` is equally dangerous when not used properly and few people know it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "Vilified" is not correct. His choice of approach is challenged. This is a fair thing to do, and gives the user a chance to improve or reply. I would also confess to not knowing how to sanitise user input properly in all cases, so the `tr` trick was useful.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I was refering to the 3 downvotes. And my objection is to vilifying `eval` which is not more dangerous than `[` when used properly.

Answer (score 3):

To give an interactive menu in `bash` from which a user may select from a number of file pathnames, you may want to use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( "$HOME/Desktop/ScreenShot-"*.png )

PS3='Select file to upload, or 0 to exit: '
select file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then
        echo 'Bye!' >&2
        exit
    elif [[ -z $file ]]; then
        echo 'Invalid choice, try again' >&2
    else
        break
    fi
done

# use scp to upload "$file" here
```

Here, we use the `bash` statement `select` to provide a menu, and the `PS3` tertiary prompt to provide the custom prompt.

The user may exit the script without selecting a file from the list by entering `0` at the prompt.  If an invalid response is given, the user is given another chance to select a file.  The menu is re-displayed by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the prompt.

How the logic inside the `select` loop is formulated is less important, as long as the script terminates when `$REPLY` (the actual value inputted by the user) is `0` and retries when `$file` (a value picked from the array) is empty.  An alternative `select` statement body might look like

```
if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then
    echo 'Bye!' >&2
    exit
elif [[ -n $file ]]; then
    break
fi

echo 'Invalid choice, try again' >&2
```

The filenames are inserted into a named array by means of a shell glob.  You could also get the relevant files from the command line of the script by using

```
files=( "$@" )
```

In an POSIX shell, you generally don't have access to named arrays or to `select`.   Instead, you could do something like

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- "$HOME/Desktop/ScreenShot-"*.png

while true; do
    i=0
    for pathname do
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
        printf '%d) %s\n' "$i" "$pathname" >&2
    done

    printf 'Select file to upload, or 0 to exit: ' >&2
    read -r reply

    number=$(printf '%s\n' "$reply" | tr -dc '[:digit:]')

    if [ "$number" = "0" ]; then
        echo 'Bye!' >&2
        exit
    elif [ "$number" -gt "$#" ]; then
        echo 'Invalid choice, try again' >&2
    else
        break
    fi
done

shift "$(( number - 1 ))"
file=$1

# use scp to upload "$file" here
```

This is a fairly common input loop that iterates until the user inputs a valid entry (or until `0` is inputted and the script exits).  The menu is re-displayed at each incorrect entry.

The pathnames are brought into the list of positional parameters by means of a shell glob, just as in the `bash` variation, but the menu is manually printed, with an integer incrementing for each outputted menu entry.

The `shift` at the end shifts off the entries at the start of the list of positional parameters so that `$1` becomes the pathname that the user wants to upload.

To instead use pathnames given on the command line, just delete the initial `set` command.